# how to use image button to open the url in another window

Tags: asp.net, validation, imagebutton, new-window

Hi I know how to acheive this in hyperlink by setting target = _blank , how can i do this using image button control , below is my code:

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClick="test_Click" ImageUrl="/images/contactUs/directionbtn.png" ID="test" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group2" />

             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtPostcode1" ErrorMessage="Postcode is required"  ValidationGroup="group2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void test_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect(String.Format("http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr={0}&daddr=&daddr=Wigan+WN6+0HS,+United+Kingdom&iwloc=1&dq=Tangent+Design", txtPostcode1.Text));



}
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated

Comment: Use an anchor as a container of the image. Or asp.net jargon, <asp:HyperLink id="foo" target="_blank" ...> <asp:Image ImageUrl="directionbtn.png" /> </asp:HyperLink>

Comment: currently the link opens ont he same page

Comment: i need to pass txtpostcode value to the link , how will i acheive that then4

Comment: ok... do it in javascript <asp:ImageButton onClientClick="foo()" />     in javascript: foo(){ var txtPostCode = document.getElementById('txtPostcode1').value;  window.open("http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=" + txtPostcode1 + "&daddr=&daddr=Wigan+WN6+0HS,+United+Kingdom&iwloc=1&dq=Tangent+Design"","MyWindow","height=375,width=350"); }  // don't forget to validate if(txtPostcode1 !== ''){foo();}

Comment: using script the validation group will not work

Answer (score 6):

```
protected void Page_Load() {
   ControlID.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");    
}
```

If that doesn't work, try adding this to your ImageButton:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('http://url/to/open');" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

Comment: should i do something like this ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");

Comment: Just curious - Why don't you just use the <asp:HyperLink> control or <asp:LinkButton>

Comment: link button doesnt support image .. and i can use hyperlink but hyperlink doesnt support onclick event:(

Comment: i tried ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank"); but still the it opens up in the same window ..

Answer (score 4):

I just figure it out..

On `Page_Load` event, put

```
    this.Form.Target = "_blank"; // Will set all link's target to a new window
```

Then for example in a image button `Click` event, you put:

```
    Response.Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

It will simply open this page in a new tab. Try it :)

Answer (score 3):

you could use the Attributes collection to add "target","_blank"

this should add the target attribute to the anchor link surrounding the image

Comment: do we have to do something like this ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");

Answer (score 3):

Add **target="_blank**" to onClientClick will do the trick

Answer (score 3):

In the code behind.

```
imgbtn.OnClientClick = "target='blank'";
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClick="test_Click" ImageUrl="/images/contactUs/directionbtn.png" ID="test" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group2" OnClientClick="form1.target ='_blank';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Form.Target = "_blank";
```

This way the client can see what he wants in a new page, since the server and what is available and his account in the site available at the beginning PageLoad